# Convoluted definition of a set: $H(S) = \{x\in G\mid\exists n\in\Bbb N,\exists\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\}\subseteq S\cup S^{-1}, x = x_1 ...x_n\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-set-theory, soft-question

Source: Reversat & Bigonnet, *Algèbre pour la licence* ( *Undergraduate abstract algebra*), Dunod ( editor), $1997$, p.$17$.

Let $G$ be a group, $S\subseteq G$, $\langle S\rangle$ is the intersection of all subgroups $H$ of $G$ such that $S\subseteq H$.

The subsequent claim is that $H(S) =\langle S\rangle$, with:

$$ H(S) = \{x\in G \mid \exists n\in \mathbb N , \exists \{x_1, x_2,...
,x_n\}\subseteq S\cup S^{-1} , x = x_1 ...x_n\}.$$

and

$S^{-1} = \{x^{-1} \mid x\in S \}$.

Before trying to understand the claim, I'd like to ***make sense of the definition of $H(S)$*** .

Could it be the case that this convoluted definition means:

> $H(S)$ is the set of all elements $g$ of $G$ such that $g$ belongs to some finite  subset of $S\cup S^{-1}$?

Comment: The elements of $H(S)$ are just finite products whose factors are elements of $S$ or inverses of elements of $S$.

Comment: @PtF is correct. The author should just have said that in words. The notation adds nothing and confuses readers. Not your fault, but your problem ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $H(S)$ is the set of all elements $g$ of $G$ such that $g$ belongs to some finite  subset of $S\cup S^{-1}$?

No. $H(S)$ is the set of all elements $g$ of $G$ such that $g$ can be expressed as a finite product of elements of $S\cup S^{-1}$.

Maybe lets have a look at example. Consider $G=\{0,1,2,3\}$ with addition modulo $4$ as group operation, i.e. $G=\mathbb{Z}_4$. Now let $S=\{2\}$. Since we are dealing with addition, then $S^{-1}=\{2\}$ because $2+2=0$ in our group. Therefore $S\cup S^{-1}=\{2\}$.

Next $H(S)$ is the set of all elements $g$ of $G$ such that $g=x_1+\cdots +x_n$ for some $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in S\cup S^{-1}$. Since our last set has exactly one element then only possibilities for $g$ are: $2$, $2+2$, $2+2+2$, and so on... which we can write in a compact way as $n\cdot 2$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. By removing duplicates (remember that $2+2=0$) this gives us

$$H(S)=\{0,2\}$$